# How to run a thread every x seconds without using timer control

Tags: vb.net

I have to run a certain thread every second refreshes the message field, but without using any time controls. I wonder if there is any alternative to timer control. My be background worker or something of that sort.

This what I have so far. It suppose to run every second but it doesn't

```
Private Sub main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim myThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetData)
    myThread.Start()
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```

And this is function which he is calling to:

```
Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal newString As String)

Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.ChatBox.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        Me.ChatBox.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub​

Sub GetData()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim Query = "SELECT * fROM messages where Time_Posted > Now()"
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
        Dim theREader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        SetText("")
        Dim Temp as String = ""
        Do While theREader.Read()
            Temp &= theREader.GetString(0) & vbCrLf
        Loop
        SetText(Temp)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        conn.Close()
    End Try
 GetData()
End Sub
```

I wonder if there any way how can I make the thread run repeatedly without using timer?

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions

THIS IS CORRECTED CODE AFTER THE PROBLEM WAS SOLVED

Comment: You want something timed without using a timer?

Comment: Yes I want something without timer

Comment: any reason? What's wrong with sleep or timer? How you want a function get called each X minute without a timer? Question is not clear

Comment: any alternative to a timer if there is any in .net

Comment: may be there is any background runner or anything of that sort which will reatterate till from is open

Comment: no problem with sleep

Comment: Time Span would work, use a do until something...

Comment: I just can't figure out how to use it properly. I set it for 1 second interval but it runs only once

Comment: can you tell me a bit more about time span?

Comment: I checked the timespan thing. but I still  have to increment it

Comment: A `Timer` is optimal, a Do/Loop would do it as well, but a Do/Loop can tie up the `UI` or run infinitely if no escape is given.

Comment: I tried this: ` Dim i As Integer = 0 Do While i < 10 myThread.Start()
    Thread.Sleep(1000) Loop`

Comment: so I don't increment i so it stays 0 all the time. But the program shuts down

Comment: Dy the way where shall I place `Thread.Sleep(1000) ` in the load sub or in the `GetData`?

Comment: Sorry if my questions may sound silly to you. I'm a bit new to Threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this one then

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Dim testvalue As Integer
    Private Sub main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim myThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetData)
        myThread.Start()
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Sub GetData()

        MsgBox("getdata works")

        'get your new data from database here
        'threadsleep here if you want

        'and call   GetData() again 

        GetData()


    End Sub
    '
    '
    '

End Class
```

Comment: hold on. let me try this one

Comment: Its great  the message is keep punping up but the messages are not being displayed

Comment: I have an error "Cross-Tread oreration not valid: Control MessBox accessed from a thread other than the tread it was created on"

Comment: What it means I have no Idea. As I said I'm a bit new to treads. Sorry

Comment: good then try to make MessBox refresher proc and invoke it from GetData()

Comment: ok I got this. I just pass the values from the database to the function SetText

Comment: I will update my post with a correct code in case someone may need it laiter

Answer (score -1):

now i gotta make non stop proc read without any timer.You can add thread sleep if you want

paste it to new project

> ```
> Public Class Form1
>     Dim testvalue As Integer
>     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>         testvalue = 1
> 'now we gotta run our proc first time 
>         Read(testvalue)
>
>
>     End Sub
>
>     Private Sub Read(ByVal msg As String)
>
>
>         MsgBox(msg)
>         testvalue += 1 'you make make threadsleep here if you want
>         Read(testvalue) 'after first start we did what we ant , and now we are running it again 
>
>     End Sub
>
> End Class
> ```

Comment: but there must me something like recursion or something

Comment: when I try to place `myThread.Start()` into the function I have and error that its not declared. Shall I re declare it there?

Comment: i would like to see your whole codes but i m editing my answer now.